# QProcess output after closeWriteChannel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

How can I run two commands and see output. something like this:

```
process.write('myVar = 2')
process.write('print myVar')
```

And see output of each my command. If I do `closeWriteChannel` to see the output, I can't communicate with my process anymore. Here's my code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
process = QProcess()
process.start('python -i')

process.waitForFinished(100)
process.readAllStandardOutput()

process.write('2+2')
process.closeWriteChannel()
process.waitForFinished(100)
print process.readAllStandardOutput()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `readyReadStandardOutput` and `readyReadStandardError` signals of `QProcess` to get notified when there's some data available to be read.

And if you want to send two lines, you just need to separate them using a newline.

Example:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

app = QCoreApplication([])
process = QProcess()

def read_out():
    print 'stdout:', str(process.readAllStandardOutput()).strip()


def read_err():
    print 'stderr:', str(process.readAllStandardError()).strip()


process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(read_out)
process.readyReadStandardError.connect(read_err)

process.start('python -i')
process.write('2+2\n')
process.write('1+1\n')

process.closeWriteChannel()
process.waitForFinished()

app.processEvents()
```

Output:

```
stderr: Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
stderr: Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
stderr: >>>
stdout: 4
stderr: >>>
stdout: 2
stderr: >>>
```

Note: There's no guarantee that the lines with `4` and `2` will be two separate reads. Could as well be

```
stderr: Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
stderr: Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
stdout: 4
2
stderr: >>> >>> >>>
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works. I forgot about "\n" at the end of command.